# How to store an array index location as an integer variable in Processing

Tags: arrays, variables, indexing, processing, extract

I have an array of fifty float values, at array index locations 0-49.

I know that the lowest value in that array is 5,278,015, at index location 19 (i.e., it is the 20th value in that array).

Is there a way in which I can extract the index location (19) and store it in a variable as an integer?

I am using Processing 3.0.

Comment: Just save the value inside as int valueMax= arr[19]
if you'll have a casting problem just write: int valueMac= (int)arr[19]

Comment: @Or251 thanks, but I'm not sure you understand my question. I have extracted the minimum value (5,278,015) using min(array) to a variable. I now want to use that variable to extract its index location (19) to another variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: If i understood, just loop over the array and save the index where min(array) equals array[i]. Is that the answer you were looking for? or something else?

Comment: @Or251 - Yes, thank you. I've just done that and it works :D This is new to me, and that might have been obvious to you - thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the answer i gave at the comments because @Kevin Workman asked for it.

just loop over the array and save the index where min(array) equals array[i].